# Oracle - Replace first occurrence of multiple values

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I would like to replace the first occurrence of multiple values in a string. Pls consider the following example :

**Input string :** `a,a,a,b,b,c`

**Values to be replaced :** `a,b`

**Expected Output :** `,a,a,,b,c`

Using the `|` operator doesn't work, as shown below :

```
select regexp_replace('a,a,a,b,b,c','a|b',null,1,1) from dual;
```

Output : `,a,a,b,b,c` . This replaces only the first occurrence of `a`.

As an extension to this, if `a` is to be replaced more than once, then the second occurrence should also be replaced in the input :

**Input string** : `a,a,a,b,b,c`

**Values to be replaced :** `a,b,a`

**Expected Output :** `,,a,,b,c`

Is this achievable using `REGEXP_REPLACE` or through something else? If yes, how? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Can you please describe rules of replacing clearer. I don't understand why second example has values to be replaced `a,b,a`.

Comment: @Kacper As I understood - `a,b,a` should replace the two first `A` and the first `B` values. `a,b` should replace first value of `A` and first value of `B` .

Comment: I don't understand the rule. Text says replace first multiple occurence so for me it means in Ex1 result is `a,b,b,c` or `a,b,c` if we treat occurence for each letter separately

Comment: You need to treat them separately , why would it become `a,b,c` ? there are 3 `a` and only 1 need to be replaced . @Kacper

Comment: replace first multiple occurence. Double is multiple but triple is also multiple @sagi

Comment: I'm not trying to argue with you weather this question in easy to understand or not, because it defiently isn't! I just explained by the output what he probably needs @Kacper

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131052/discussion-between-kacper-and-sagi).

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use two `regexp_replace()`s:

```
select regexp_replace(regexp_replace('a,a,a,b,b,c', 'a', null, 1, 1), 'b', null, 1, 1)
from dual;
```

I'm not sure if there is a (reasonable) solution using a single regular expression.

Comment: There's no way you can get a general solution from this. For a very special one, you might as well do it with one regexp_replace: `select regexp_replace(input_string, input_string, output_string)`. Yes, hard-code all three arguments. Or, even better: `select output_string`. No worse than what is proposed in this answer.

Comment: @mathguy . . . I have no idea what your comment is supposed to be saying.  This answer replaces the first occurrence of the "a" and of the "b", which is what the OP is asking for.

Comment: So you assume if the input was `x,x,x,y,y,z` he should still remove the first `a` and the first `b`? He said "first occurrence of **multiple values**", not first occurrence of `a` and `b`.

Comment: @mathguy . . . The initial question is quite clear:  "a,a,a,b,b,c" --> ",a,a,,b,c".  The first "a" is replaced.  The first "b" is replaced.  I have no idea how you are reading the question, but it seems very clear.

Comment: @mathguy . . . The OP *does* say explicitly "Values to be replaced : a,b".  Those seem to be the values s/he wants replaced.

Comment: Yes. After "Please consider the following example." Did you see that part? I don't know what to think - do you just read 15% of a question and start writing your solutions, or are you really having difficulty understanding what people are asking? You may not like it, but I will keep calling you out on this kind of answers when I think it's needed (while I will continue to upvote your good answers, as I have done many times). This one doesn't look too good.

Answer (score 0):

I guess might be more better solution.

I could do this only with recursive SQL =(
Looks on script below :

```
with replaced_string as (
    select 'a,a,a,b,c,b,d,a,d' as str   from dual union all
    select 'a,a,a,b,c,d,a,d,d' as str   from dual
)
,expr_for_replace as (
    select 'a,b,a,d' as pattern from dual
)
,recursive_call (str, lvl, parent_str) as (
    select t.str as str, 1 as lvl, t.str as parent_str
    from replaced_string t
    union all
    select case
             when regexp_instr(r.str, v.val, 1, 2) > 0
             then regexp_replace(r.str,v.val,null,1,1)
             else r.str
           end str
          ,r.lvl + 1 as lvl
          ,r.parent_str as parent_str
    from recursive_call r
    left join (select regexp_substr(pattern, '[^,]+',1,level) as val
                     ,level as lvl
               from expr_for_replace
               connect by regexp_substr(pattern, '[^,]+',1,level) is not null) v on (v.lvl = r.lvl)
    where v.lvl is not null
)

select parent_str as string_before
      ,str        as result_string
from (select c.*
            ,row_number() over(partition by parent_str order by c.lvl desc) as rn
      from recursive_call c)
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do this in full generality. If I understood the problem correctly, given a comma-separated string, replace each symbol (token) that is repeated later in the string with `NULL` - but keep all the commas as placeholders. The solution covers the case when the original string already had such placeholders for `NULL` (that is, consecutive commas with no tokens between them). In the extreme, the original string may also be empty (same as `NULL` in Oracle).

The only other reasonable meaning of the problem is that "symbols" or "tokens" should be removed only when they are IMMEDIATELY followed by the same symbol. That is, an input like `a,a,a,b,b,a,a,b,b,b` should become `,,a,,b,,a,,,b`. In the first interpretation, it should become `,,,,,,a,,,b`. The solution below implements the "first interpretation" (where there is only one `a` and one `b` left in the modified string); the OP's question is not clear as to which interpretation is desired. If the "second interpretation" is desired, the solution below can be modified (using the elementary "Tabibitosan method" to identify consecutive same-values).

The solution splits each string - carefully, since there may be `NULL` tokens, then it identifies the last occurrence of each distinct symbol, replaces all null tokens and all tokens that are not "last in group" with a placeholder symbol (here I used '~' - it should be a symbol not used in the input strings), it then aggregates everything with `LISTAGG()` and removes all the placeholder symbols (`~`). The placeholders are needed because `LISTAGG()` removes `NULL`s from its inputs (a regrettable choice made by the Oracle developers).

The solution uses regular expressions; they can be avoided (use `INSTR` and `SUBSTR` instead) if performance is very important - at the cost of making the code more complicated.

```
with
-- begin test data definition (do not include in final query)
     test_data as (
       select 1 as id, 'a,a,a,b,b,c' as str from dual union all
       select 2      , ''                   from dual union all
       select 3      , 'a,b,a,b,b,a'        from dual union all
       select 4      , 'x,y,z,z,z'          from dual union all
       select 5      , 'a,a,a,a'            from dual union all
       select 6      , 'a,b,c,c,a'          from dual union all
       select 7      , 'x'                  from dual union all
       select 8      , 'p,q,r'              from dual union all
       select 9      , 'a,b,,,a,c'          from dual
     ),
-- end of test data; solution (query) continues below this line
     prep as (
       select id, str, level as lvl,
              regexp_substr(str, '([^,]*)(,|$)', 1, level, null, 1) as token
       from   test_data
       connect by level <= regexp_count(str, ',') + 1
              and prior id = id
              and prior sys_guid() is not null
     ),
     with_rn as (
       select id, str, lvl, token,
              row_number() over (partition by id, token order by lvl desc) as rn
       from   prep              
     )
select id, str, 
       translate( listagg ( case when token is null or rn > 1 then '~'
                                 else token end, ','
                          ) within group (order by lvl), 'x~', 'x'
                ) as modif_str
from  with_rn
group by id, str
;
```

**Output**:

```
 ID STR            MODIF_STR
--- -------------- --------------
  1 a,a,a,b,b,c    ,,a,,b,c
  2
  3 a,b,a,b,b,a    ,,,,b,a
  4 x,y,z,z,z      x,y,,,z
  5 a,a,a,a        ,,,a
  6 a,b,c,c,a      ,b,,c,a
  7 x              x
  8 p,q,r          p,q,r
  9 a,b,,,a,c      ,b,,,a,c

9 rows selected.
```